# HttpPost to web api is always a null parater

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post some data to a web api app from an angular 2 app. Its only a small json string and when I hit the web api controller, the item is always null - no matter what I've tried.

The json is  (I can see this from alerting the data)

```
{"firstname":"Joe","lastname":"Bloggs"}
```

The angular function is

```
    createUser(user: Profile): Observable<Response> {

    let url = this.usersUrl;
    let data = JSON.stringify(user);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(url, data, options);
}
```

The web api conroller method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(User item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        Users.Add(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { id = item.Id }, item);
    }
```

but when I break point at Create the User item is null.

I've tried :

```
   public IActionResult Create([FromBody] User item)
```

but the error message in the Chrome console window is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

I've tried

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' });
```

but the error is the same as above.

Any ideas?:)

Comment: use `JSON.parse()` instead of `JSON.stringify()` over here

     let data = JSON.stringify(user); if you have json string else dont use any thing just do      let data =  user;

Comment: Won't work.User is a class with firstname, lastname properties. Error message - won't compile type Profile is not assignable to parameter of type string.

Comment: try this signature for the contorller method public IHttpActionResult Create(JObject user)

Comment: ha. What sado marked it down?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that your problem is your user model in API. The properties need to be exactly equals.